# Batch file closes program after executing command. How to stop this?

Tags: batch-file, automation, command-prompt, execute

I have a program that uses batch scripts internally since I do not have the newer software to that will allow me to create an exe to run inside the program. This is for my job, so I cannot purchase software and make it happen myself. So my work around with what I have is to create a batch file for a script that will run it automatically from within the program when clicking its icon. Problem is (50/50) when I run the .bat the command prompt opens and runs just fine then closes the command prompt after executing. Good. But then It also closes my program and I do not know how to prevent it from doing so. Is there something I need to add to the command prompt that will not close the program i am using the script in?

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JDA\Intactix\Space Automation\autopilot.exe" /play "C:\Users\Public\Documents\AAA SWB Custom\SCRIPTS\SWB - Desc 39 Survey Date.aps"
```

The autopilot.exe opens up Space Automation where scripts are written and played. The command prompt opens this program and runs the script then closes the program and the command prompt. But for some reason it also closes the program I am running it in.

Comment: try `START "sometext and possibly empty but not missing" "C:\prog.....` - I got lost in your `50/50` and what this `cmd` line does - where it is in your program, and precise consequences of running it.

Comment: There is no need to use a batch file to run an application. On your Windows Desktop and in your Windows Start menu are lots of shortcut files which start an application without using a batch file and without using `cmd.exe`. Navigate in Windows File Explorer to the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\JDA\Intactix\Space Automation\autopilot.exe`, right click on it and click in submenu __Send to__ on item __Desktop (create shortcut)__. On your Windows Desktop is now a shortcut for `autopilot.exe`. Rename this file to something meaningful for you. Then right click on this shortcut file, click ...

Comment: ... on last item __Properties__ and modify property __Target__ by appending the argument strings to pass by Windows to `autopilot.exe` on starting it. You can most likely define also a different __Start in__ directory if the application is not bad coded.

Comment: The reason to use the batch file is to make the script more of an automation and ease for the people using it. The poeple using this are not very computer savy so it is our way of making it the simplest we can. Also, we do not want them opening up the space automation and trying to open the script and play it from there as well as change the code. This way, they only have to push the one button and the script runs in the background and they dont have to do anything else.

Comment: when i say 50/50 i mean it doesnt close space planning everytime. It only closes it randomly at different times under same circumstances that it completes the job successfully.

Comment: it does close the command prompt window after executing. Which is good. Just not sure why it is also closing my program sometimes

Answer (score 0):

ignore what i am saying and just copy the code lol kasdijkiojoipgo mipogaio goi juioj oiefj ioqj iojioqejoqeg oeiqwjc oij qoijfq oije oije fgiououimgqiou moi gq mqeo meqoio imo igoiqe eogeoqi jioqejgo joi moeigeqoi mgoi mohij rowt pokjpoq jpoerig iopw4i gmjwreo miomgwpj gioj

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\JDA\Intactix\Space Automation\"
autopilot.exe /play "C:\Users\Public\Documents\AAA SWB Custom\SCRIPTS\SWB - Desc 39 Survey Date.aps"
```

or just

```
 cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\JDA\Intactix\Space Automation\"
  start autopilot.exe /play "C:\Users\Public\Documents\AAA SWB Custom\SCRIPTS\SWB - Desc 39 Survey Date.aps"
```

I hope i helped you.